# Save filenames in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, filenames, winsock, send

I have this function:

```
void f_listfiles(char temp[200]){
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    int i;

    hFind = FindFirstFile("*", &FindData);

    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))
    {
    strcpy(temp, FindData.cFileName);

    }

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

I want it to put the filenames in the directory in to char temp. After that i am going to send it to a FTP client. How can i do this? It currently overwrites each time and only the last file is in the char temp.

Edit:I cant use an array of pointers due to the fact that i later need to send this array with the function send(clientSocket, temp, sizeof(temp), 0)

Comment: Use need to use 2D array or array of pointers.

Comment: I cant use an array of pointers due to the fact that i later need to send this array to a client.

Comment: When you say "send", what do you mean by that?

Comment: @JacobÅkerblom: So? Why wouldn't you be able to handle that? Besides: `void f_listfiles(char temp[200])` should be `void f_listfiles( char *temp)` because arrays decay into pointers when you pass them to functions

Comment: Your `temp` array can hold 199 characters. So anyway if the sum of the lengths of all files on your directory exceeds 199 (which is likely to occur) you won't be able to store all filenames in your array anyway.

Comment: assuming the temp is long enough (it probably is not) you could memset( temp, '\0', 200 );  then where you currently call strcpy() call strcat( temp, FindData.cFileName );  of course, the code needs to check that there is enough room in temp for the new file name before actually copying it.  I suggest locally define temp as a pointer to char then realloc( temp, strlen(temp)+strlen(FindData.cFileName)+1 just before doing the strcat() then return the temp var (a pointer) with the expectation that the caller would free the pointer when done with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want it to put the filenames in the directory in to `char temp[]`

That is not going to work: a character array is a single string; you need an array of strings.

That is, you need an array of pointers. There are several ways of making it work. One is to let the caller pass an array, along with its length to avoid overruns, and then allocate strings dynamically as you go. You need to return how many entries you filled in, otherwise the caller would not know where in his array the actual file names end.

```
size_t f_listfiles(char *names[], size_t max) {
    HANDLE hFind;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindData;
    size_t i = 0;
    hFind = FindFirstFile("*", &FindData);
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData) && i != max)
    {
        names[i] = malloc(strlen(FindData.cFileName)+1);
        strcpy(names[i], FindData.cFileName);
        i++;
    }
    FindClose(hFind);
    return i;
}
```

The caller would call your function like this:

```
char *names[200];
size_t count = f_listfiles(names, 200);
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
    printf("%02d: %s\n", i+1, names[i]);
}
// Caller needs to free dynamically allocated strings:
for (size_t i = 0 ; i != count ; i++) {
    free(names[i]);
}
```

> I later need to send this array to a client

The code that sends this array would need to serialize it in some way - say, append strings one by one to a character buffer before sending.

Comment: Note that an array of strings isn't necessary if all you need is to join them later. You could copy all of them in a one-dimensional array and keep a pointer which will be incremented by the length of the last copied string.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that *temp* maybe too small to handle or the strings you can do the following to overcome the *overwrite* problem:

```
int i = 0;
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))
{
    if(i == 0){
        strcpy(temp, FindData.cFileName);
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    strcat(temp, FindData.cFileName);
}
```

or

```
temp[0] = 0; //terminating null character so strcat can join the strings
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindData))
{
    strcat(temp, FindData.cFileName);
}
```

There is a *catch* though. The `strcat` will ovewrite the `terminating null character` of the *temp* string and append a new one in the end of the resulting string